# Integrating notebooks to Mathematica's documentation center

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

If you have been using *Mathematica* for a while you probably have grown attached to the documentation center. There is always something new that you find in those pages. Let it be options for a function or just some examples that at some point did not seem useful to you.

It is likely that you have written packages with your specialized functions that you use all the time. Sometimes you might think of a neat example to use with your function but it is likely that it ends up being forgotten somewhere in your hard disk. If you had written it to the documentation at the moment you thought of it maybe you wouldn't be looking for it desperately later on.

For this reason I would like to know how to integrate documentation for your own functions with *Mathematica's* documentation center programmatically. This question is here to explore how to adapt documentation. If you have written scripts that help you do this, please share it with the community.

Wolfram's Workbench is not an acceptable solution for this question. Everything must be done with the plain installation of *Mathematica*. There is a couple of points that the solution should cover:

1. Creating documentation for a function (Preferably a template).
2. Creating guides and tutorials (If they are deem useful).
3. Linking the notebooks to the documentation center.
4. Creating "usage" messages that display correctly in different enviroments.

   - In Mathematica Notebook `?Symbol`
   - In Documentation Center `Search: Symbol`

This is a really broad topic, I have solutions for 1, 2, and 3. I'm missing point number 4. So tell us, how do you document your functions with the documentation center?

---

#### Update

I have added another answer. Hopefully this answer is more encouraging to users of Mathematica to write documentation pages with their packages. I think that writing documentation pages is beneficial to the application writer as well as the users of the application. If you download the package I wrote I suggest you follow the tutorial so that you can see what happens in every step. This will give you valuable experience for future projects.

#### Github (May 24, 2014)

Since I wrote the package there has been several people interested in this package. I have uploaded the package to Github: https://github.com/jmlopez-rod/ApplicationMaker. Please contact me if you would like to be a contributor to the repository.

Comment: I'd suggest that you reformulate it as a question, a.s.a.p. The SO format is that the question is asked and then some answers are given. If you later have some ideas on the matter, you may become one of the answerers. Here is a recent example of the acceptable format:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505675/watching-for-new-mathematica-questions-using-mathematica-and-the-stackoverflow-ap.  Note that, leaving your post as it is will most likely lead to the question being closed (regardless of what the local mma community members think of its value).

Comment: But I do have a question there.  Would it suffice if I ask the question very vaguely like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570770/formatting-usage-messages) and then just answer partially so that everyone knows what's going on? I could've put this on the last post but @Szabolcs pointed out that this was a different question.

Comment: You can ask something like "How to programmatically integrate the documentation into the documentation center", and then post the rest of your current post as (one of the) answers. This is an important topic, so having such a question and also the information you accumulated as one of the answers will be very beneficial for all of us.

Comment: @Leonid, I hope this is enough for the question. I'll write what I have for an answer.

Comment: @Leonid Completely agree. I think this question is an important one, but ought to be written carefully. @jmlopez: Do you want to add personal notes to existing help? Extending the docs to your own functions/ packages? Replacing the default help pages? Other?

Comment: @belisarius, I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. But yes, the main idea is that I want to be able to write my functions and a documentation page with examples. I know I will forget how to use them in a month so I'd like to be able to open it up in the doc center.

Comment: @belisarius, I'm glad you think this is an important question. I apologize for the way I have written it. I think I need to take a break for right now.

Comment: @jmlopez All we are trying to do is to save this valuable question from closing. The SO rules are what they are, and there are lots of people around willing to enforce them. I wish there was an acceptable blog-style SO format, but if one has to formulate a question in order to deliver some valuable information to others, so be it. It is not a critique of your effort, by any means.

Comment: @jmlopez Take your time and rewrite it in a way others feel compelled to contribute.

Comment: @Leonid, I really appreciate your support and belisarius. I will go get something to eat and reformulate the question once again. Hopefully some nutrients will help me think more clearly and it won't be too late.

Comment: @jmlopez Just as @belisarius suggested, take your time - no need to rush at this point, I think.

Comment: @belisarius and @Leonid, well, I ate and I wrote. I hope this is a valid question now.

Comment: This would be a good candidate for integration with [the IDEA plugin](http://wlplugin.halirutan.de/) ...

Comment: @Szabolcs, it has been a while since I've been here so I just got to read your comment. Glad you think so, I've been using intellij for a while now and I love it. I do wish I could have some time to work on Mathematica again but I no longer have the software nor a license. There is so much that we can do with the stuff I wrote (get rid of the notebooks to begin with). Either way, if anyone is interested on doing this please go for it. Hopefully one day I'll come back to using this awesome software (Mathematica that is).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It took me while but I have finally finished writing a documented Mathematica application to help Mathematica users write their documented packages.

This application is called `ApplicationMaker`. It contains three packages with various functions to help you create the application. By using these functions you can skip going through all the mess I had described in my previous answer.

If you download `ApplicationMaker` from my website you will find a detailed tutorial showing you how to create a complete application with its documentation.

### Overview

To create a new application you start by calling `NewApplication`. This creates the directory tree I mentioned in the previous answer. To find more about Mathematica's file organization click [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaFileOrganization.html).

The next step is to create the packages. For that you call `NewPackage`. This function creates a template where you write your code.

When you finish writing your code you need to call `UpdateInit`. This updates the init file that Mathematica needs so that you can use the function `Get (<<)`.

At this point you are ready to create the documentation. Simply call `CreateReferencePages` and this will create a basic document that you can edit to document the reference pages for each symbol in your application.

If you want to create a guide or a tutorial for your application then you can call `NewGuide` and `NewTutorial`.

When you are done doing your edits you need to build your application so that Mathematica can adapt it to its documentation center. You do this by calling `BuildApplication`.

At this point you are done. If you use `Information` on any of the symbols of your package you should see an arrow appended that leads you to the reference page for that symbol.

If you wish to share this application you should first deploy it. The current application contains the reference pages which work with the documentation center and those that you edit. By deploying it you obtain a directory with only the necessary files for your application to work.

### Installation

All you have to do is drop the folder `ApplicationMaker` in `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications/` or `$BaseDirectory/Applications/`.

To get started open up the documentation center and look for "ApplicationMaker". This should show you the guide showing all the functions that the package contains. At the very bottom you should see a link to the tutorial.

### Final Words

This is the first application I have ever build for Mathematica. I will try to keep updating the package I as discover new things to make the package better. For now, I hope that this first version of ApplicationMaker is useful to anybody trying to document their Mathematica applications.

You may download ApplicationMaker [here](https://github.com/jmlopez-rod/ApplicationMaker).

Comment: I forgot to mention that this package was written in Mathematica 8. I have not tested it in previous versions.

Comment: Some minor fixes: 1) Rename "Init.m" to "init.m" in the `UpdateInit` function so that applications work on case-sensitive filesystems. 2) In `CreateReferencePages` fix `StyleDefinitions->...` so it points to a style-sheet that exists. 3) `WholeCellGroupOpener` should be `System<BACKTICK>WholeCellGroupOpener` for "Basic Examples" etc to be expand/collapsable by clicking on them directly, and not just the gray triangle. But that makes it hard to change the "(#)". Thanks again, good documentation and easy-to-follow code

Comment: I would correct the following to `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]` and `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]` so they are copy and pastable.

Answer (score 49):

To show how to create documentation that incorporates to the Documentation Center we will create a package that contains very simple functions and its documentation. Lets call our package `SOPackage`. This package will be stored in a folder of the same name and such folder should be stored in either `$BaseDirectory` or `$UserBaseDirectory$`. The `SOPakage` folder needs to have the following tree structure.

[image]

Notice that the root is the directory `SOPackage`.

### SOPackage

Now we will create a new notebook file inside `SOPackage`: `SOPackage.nb`. These are the contents of the notebook

```
BeginPackage["SOPackage`"];
AddTwo::usage = "AddTwo[\!\(\*StyleBox[\"a\", \"TI\"]\), \!\(\*StyleBox[\"b\", \"TI\"]\)] returns \!\(\*StyleBox[\"a\", \"TI\"]\)+\!\(\*StyleBox[\"b\", \"TI\"]\).";
DotTwo::usage = "DotTwo[\!\(\*StyleBox[\"a\", \"TI\"]\), \!\(\*StyleBox[\"b\", \"TI\"]\)] returns \!\(\*StyleBox[\"a\", \"TI\"]\)*\!\(\*StyleBox[\"b\", \"TI\"]\).";
AddTwo::argnum = "AddTwo was called with `1` arguments. It expected 2.";
DotTwo::argnum = "DotTwo was called with `1` arguments. It expected 2.";
Begin["`Private`"];
AddTwo[a_, b_] := a + b
AddTwo[args___] := (Message[AddTwo::argnum, Length[{args}]]; $Failed)
DotTwo[a_, b_] := a*b
DotTwo[args___] := (Message[DotTwo::argnum, Length[{args}]]; $Failed)
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Here is a screenshot of what you should see

[image: SOPackage]

Note that the usage messages usually format parameters in a special way. A shortcut to get this format (pointed out by @alexey-popkov) is to highlight the letter you want to format, press <kbd>Command+0</kbd> (<kbd>Alt+0</kbd> in windows) and enter "TI". Repeat this process for all the letters that need to be modified. Change the cell to an Initialization Cell via `Cell->CellProperties->Initialization Cell`. Now we save this notebook as `SOPackage.nb`. In case *Mathematica* did not ask you if you want to create a package because you forgot to change the cell to an initialization cell then you can go to `Format->OptionInspector`. Make sure you are selecting "Options for SOPackage.nb" otherwise the option that you need to set to true will be grayed out. Now click to `Notebook Options->FileOptions->AutoGeneratedPackage` and select `Automatic`. Close the options window and save the file. Every time you save `SOPackage.nb` the file `SOPackage.m` will get updated (Do not mess with this m file).

The `Kernel` directory should contain only one file: `init.m`. This file needs to have the next line:

```
Get["SOPackage`SOPackage`"];
```

After this we have a working package. You can try the following to make sure that everything is working fine:

```
<<SOPackage`
?AddTwo
?DotTwo
DotTwo[]
DotTwo[2, 3]
```

[image: Test]

### Documentation

Lets us start by creating the guide page. This will be the page that will show up when you type `SOPackage` in the doc center. Lets start by creating a notebook and saving it under `SOPackage/Documentation/English/Guides` as `SOPackage_E.nb`. The reason I'm giving it the extension "_E" is because this will be an editable copy. Notice that you cannot edit any of the documents in the documentation center. Well, you can but these changes never take effect. You will probably want to modify your documentation as you build your package so it is a good idea to have a copy that you can edit. For this example we can copy the contents of the `Combinatorica guide`, on the Doc center type `Combinatorica/guide/CombinatoricaPackage` select all with cells, copy and paste them in your `SOPackage_E.nb` file (alternatively, copy the file `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.4\Documentation\English\Packages\Combinatorica\Documentation\English\Guides\CombinatoricaPackage.nb` or something equivalent on other OSes). Make some changes just so that you know they are the ones you are making. In my case I substituted Combinatorica with SOPackage. In the case you can cannot modify some part of a text this is what you need to do:

1: Click on the text that you cannot modify.

[image]

2: Go to `Cell->Show Expression` or enter `Command+Shift+E` or something equivalent in windows.

[image]

3: Look for the second argument in the `Cell` expression (right before any options of the form `A -> B`). This is a style name. In some cases you will see "Usage", "Notes", "ObjectName" among others. Once you locate the style of the cell that you cannot modify go click on the notebook you are editing and enter `Command+Shift+E` to show back the expression.

4: Go to `Format->Edit StyleSheet...`, enter the style name you saw earlier under `Enter a style name:`.

[image]

5: A cell showing the style appears. Make sure this cell is selected and go to `Format->Object Inspector`. Make sure it says `Show option values` <kbd>Selection</kbd>.

6: Go to `Editing Options` and set `Editable` to true.

[image]

7: Modify the unmodifiable.

[image]

I suggest you first enter the name of all the styles that you want to be able to edit as I have shown in the screenshot. So far I have only changed the ones that I mentioned in step 3. Once you have them in the list select them all and set the to editable at once. Another important point is that this file can be a template. You should save this file somewhere and when you need to make a documentation just open it up, save it with another name in the right path and start copying cells from existing documentation notebooks.

It is up to you how you create this guide. For now lets just put nonsense. You'll see my screenshots. The next two files are the documentation for your functions. Copy and paste your template file to `SOPackage/Documentation/English/ReferencePages/Symbols` and name the files `AddTwo_E.nb` and `DotTwo_E.nb`. Look for some documentation that you like, take `Sin` for instance, and copy and paste the information to those files. I'll change the names just to show how they work.

<sup>The creation of the template file can surely be reduced. If someone knows how to do this programmatically please feel free to edit this section here and replace it with the code. You'll do us all a huge favor.</sup>

### PacletInfo.m

This file goes right under the directory `SOPackage` and contains the following:

```
Paclet[
Name -> "SOPackage",
Version -> "0.0.1",
MathematicaVersion -> "8+",
Extensions -> {{
    "Documentation", 
    Resources -> {
        "Guides/SOPackage"
    }, 
    Language -> "English"
}}
]
```

There is one last thing we must do before we can have the documenation ready. We need to make all of the function documentation uneditable and we have to give it the same format as the rest of the documents. This time I wrote a script that does this. I call it MakeDoc because it will also build the index. Save this file under `OSPackage`. I will break this file intwo 4 parts so that you can get an explanation.

```
pname = "SOPackage";
Get[pname <> "`"];
basepath = $UserBaseDirectory<>"/Applications/"<>pname<>"/Documentation/English/ReferencePages/Symbols/";
$UserBaseDirectory <> "/Applications/" <> pname <> "/Documentation/English/ReferencePages/Symbols/";
```

We should make sure that we restart Mathematica before doing this. First we will load the package and set the root directory of all of the function documentation. On the next step we will basically copy an paste code, we will be doing the following for each function.

```
snname := "AddTwo";
nb = NotebookOpen[basepath <> snname <> "_E.nb"];
NotebookSave[nb, basepath <> snname <> ".nb"];
SetOptions[nb,
  TaggingRules -> {
    "ModificationHighlight" -> False,
    "Metadata" -> {
      "context" -> pname <> "`",
      "keywords" -> {},
      "index" -> True,
      "label" -> "OSPackage Package Paclet Symbol",
      "language" -> "en",
      "paclet" -> "OSPackage Package",
      "status" -> "",
      "summary" -> AddTwo::usage,
      "synonyms" -> {},
      "title" -> "AddTwo",
      "type" -> "Symbol",
      "uri" -> pname <> "/ref/AddTwo"},
    "SearchTextTranslated" -> ""
    }
  ];
SetOptions[nb, Saveable -> False];
SetOptions[nb, 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{"Wolfram"}, "Reference.nb"]];
NotebookSave[nb];
```

This block of code opens the editable function documentation. It saves it with the correct name. And then it changes its attributes so that its not editable and it gives it the same look as the rest of the documents. We do the same for each function. Notice that "summary" is set to the `usage` message of the function. This is what we will see when we search for the function.

```
snname := "DotTwo";
nb = NotebookOpen[basepath <> snname <> "_E.nb"];
NotebookSave[nb, basepath <> snname <> ".nb"];
SetOptions[nb,
  TaggingRules -> {
    "ModificationHighlight" -> False,
    "Metadata" -> {
      "context" -> pname <> "`",
      "keywords" -> {},
      "index" -> True,
      "label" -> "OSPackage Package Paclet Symbol",
      "language" -> "en",
      "paclet" -> "OSPackage Package",
      "status" -> "",
      "summary" -> DotTwo::usage,
      "synonyms" -> {},
      "title" -> "DotTwo",
      "type" -> "Symbol",
      "uri" -> pname <> "/ref/DotTwo"},
    "SearchTextTranslated" -> ""
    }
  ];
SetOptions[nb, Saveable -> False];
SetOptions[nb, 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{"Wolfram"}, "Reference.nb"]];
NotebookSave[nb];
```

Very important, we haven't modified the guide, this is all it takes:

```
snname := "SOPackage";
nb = NotebookOpen[guidepath <> snname <> "_E.nb"];
NotebookSave[nb, guidepath <> snname <> ".nb"];
SetOptions[nb, Saveable -> False];
SetOptions[nb, StyleDefinitions -> FrontEnd`FileName[{"Wolfram"}, "Reference.nb"]];
NotebookSave[nb];
```

And finally, we create the index like this:

```
indir = $UserBaseDirectory<>"/Applications/"<>pname<>"/Documentation/English/Index";
If[FileNames[indir] != {}, DeleteDirectory[indir, DeleteContents -> True]];
ind = DocumentationSearch`NewDocumentationNotebookIndexer[indir];
DocumentationSearch`AddDocumentationNotebook[ind, basepath <> "AddTwo.nb"];
DocumentationSearch`AddDocumentationNotebook[ind, basepath <> "DotTwo.nb"];
DocumentationSearch`CloseDocumentationNotebookIndexer[ind];
```

Notice that we need to a line with `AddDocumenationNotebook` for each function. After running `MakeDoc.nb` the files `AddTwo.nb`, `DotTwo.nb` and `SOPackage.nb` will be created. These files cannot be modifed. You will also see a folder named `Index`. This is all binary data that contains information for the doc center. If you ever make a modification to the documentation you should run `MakeDoc.nb` to make the changes take effect. Here is the document tree that we have now.

[image]

After this we should restart Mathematica and take our documentation for a ride.

This is what happens when you look for "SOPackage".

[image]

Lets look for the usage of `AddTwo`

[image]

Notice that an arrow with a link to the doc page was added automatically.

Unfortunately, if we search for `AddTwo` in the doc center this is what we obtain:

[image]

How can we make it so that the summary for the function isn't formatted?

Feel free to modify my code by downloading it from [here](http://math.uh.edu/~jmlopez/tmp/Mathematica/SOPackage.zip).

Thank you for reading.

Manuel

Comment: Does this require mma's workbench or will only the plain installation do?

Comment: @d00b, this works for the plain installation of Mathematica 8. I don't really like using tools like WorkBench. I like to find out their interworkings instead.

Comment: +1 Nice tutorial. Looks like an awful lot of work though. Not something to encourage one to write ones own documentation. I guess it should be WRI's job to make this somewhat user friendlier. As it is now you have to jump through a lot of hoops. How's your experience with generating documentation using the Workbench?

Comment: @jmlopez: Very cool... from what I could understand from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419830/convenient-way-to-add-inline-formatting-to-usage-messages), you needed the workbench to neatly format stuff, but perhaps not...

Comment: @Sjoerd, Thanks, yeah, after I saw what I had written it seemed like a lot of work. I'm already thinking of written scripts and I will update my post once I have a shorter version. I only used Workbench to see how it organized the files but I haven't tried it ever since.

Comment: @d00b, I may be describing it wrong, but from what I can see workbench is a tool that keeps the files organized (Seems like another dreamweaver to me). Workbench still uses Mathematica to write the documentation. So really, all you need to know is how everything is connected and make a neat script to help you organize your functions and the documentation.

Comment: Seems a lot of work without any warranty that the v9 help system will be compatible ... :(

Comment: @belisarius, that is one thing I'm afraid. I was able to come up with this using what I found on for mathematica 6.0 and there has been differences. I'm sure if a small package is done right for this there won't have to be too much major work to adjust to the next version.

Comment: @jmlopez.  Thanks for the great tutorial.  I am still working through it, but I have learned a lot. One question:  In your code immmediatly after _Very important, we haven't modified the guide ..._, what is **guidepath**?.  Is it `$UserBaseDirectory <> "/Applications/" <> pname <> \
"/Documentation/English/Guides/"`?

Comment: @TomD, you are very right. It seems that I didn't copy and paste that correctly. If you download the example you'll see that it guidepath is what you mentioned.

Comment: @belisarius, I posted another answer. In this answer I provide a link to a package to help you write applications with documentation. Hopefully it will work with the v9 help system. If it doesn't I'll take up the challenge to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

I have downloaded your ApplicationMaker and is testing it out using Mathematica 10 on Windows 7 64 Bit. Great work and well documented! I discovered a small error that needed a fix on my set up when creating a new application using `NewApplication`. It appears that the variable `root` in the function `MakeDirectory` cannot be a string with zero length (causes error in creating the directories). I fixed this by including a test in your original code:

```
MakeDirectory[root_, start_, main_, sub_] := Module[
  {nm, ns, tmp},
  nm = Position[main, start];
  If[Length@nm != 0, nm = nm[[1, 1]]];
  If[Length@sub[[nm]] != 0,
   Do[
    tmp = 
     If[StringLength[root] != 0, 
      FileNameJoin[{root, start, sub[[nm, i]]}], 
      FileNameJoin[{start, sub[[nm, i]]}]];
    If[DirectoryQ[tmp], 
     Print[Style["Existing Directory : ", "MSG", Gray], 
      Style[tmp, "MSG", Bold]], 
     CreateDirectory[tmp];
     Print[Style["Directory Created  : ", "MSG", Blue], 
      Style[tmp, "MSG", Bold]]
     ];
    , {i, Length@sub[[nm]]}]
   ];
  Do[
   MakeDirectory[
    If[StringLength[root] != 0, FileNameJoin[{root, start}], start], 
    sub[[nm, i]], main, sub],
   {i, Length@sub[[nm]]}
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: You should make a pull request in the github repository of the package. :)